# Date field in Mongodb - Group IDs by date field Year- Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having trouble with a customer request. I have following data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : "6489", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2014-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6490", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2014-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6491", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2014-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6492", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2014-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6493", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2015-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6494", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2015-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6495", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2016-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6496", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2016-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6497", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2016-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6498", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2016-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6499", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2016-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
{ 
    "_id" : "6500", 
    "post_date" : ISODate("2017-12-20T17:00:00.000+0000"), 
    "post_modified" : ISODate("2014-06-28T14:33:57.000+0000")
}
```

I need to output a table showing the year (posting_date) and the number of posts (_id). IN SQL this would be a count _id and a grouping by posting_date(year).

The problem is the format of the posting_date, from which I have to extract the year. The format is as follows:

```
 "post_date" : ISODate("0105-08-17T00:00:00.000+0000")
```

I already wrote a code, but it didn't work. Here's my code:

```
db.posts.aggregate(
    [
    {
       $project:
         {
           year: { $year: "$post_date" }
         }
     },
        { 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "post_date" : "$post_date"
                }, 
                "COUNT(_id)" : {
                    "$sum" : NumberInt(1)
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : NumberInt(0), 
                "COUNT(_id)" : "$COUNT(_id)", 
                "post_date" : "$_id.post_date"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$sort" : {
                "COUNT(_id)" : NumberInt(-1)
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

Does anyone have an idea or find the bug in my code? I would be very happy about help. 
The Output should look like that:

```
post_date   number of posts
2014    4
2015    2
2016    5
2017    1
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Jeem

Comment: Remove first project stage and change  $group to `{ 
            "$group" : {
                "_id" : {
                    "post_date" :{ $year: "$post_date" }
                }, 
                "COUNT(_id)" : {
                    "$sum" : NumberInt(1)
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: Hi Veeram, that worked, thank you so much!